# Error of displaying data in server side datatables (Angular)

Tags: html, ajax, angular, typescript, datatables

I'm fairly new in using Angular. At the moment I'm implementing datatables into a webpage. For that, I'm following this guide: https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/basic/server-side-angular-way.

Despite the guide, I gave it my own twist. Resulting in a buggy datatable. 
No pagination, all names on one page, data gets lost after searching for a name,..

I make use of forkJoin inside the dtOptions, maybe that's the bug? Anyone got an idea?

**My code**

```
export class NewPackageComponent implements OnInit {
  dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};
  pageEvent: PageEvent;
  clickedTransactionID: string;
  packagesArray: string[]

  constructor(public packageToolkitService: PackageToolkitService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    let that = this;

    this.dtOptions = {
      pagingType: 'full_numbers',
      pageLength: 10,
      processing: true,
      ajax: (dataTablesParameters: any, callback) => {
        forkJoin([that.packageToolkitService.getPackages()])
          .subscribe(packages => {
            that.packagesArray = packages[0]['packageNames']
          })
      }
    };
  }
```

**PackageToolkitService**

```
getPackages() {
    return this.http.get(buildUrl('.gui.wmPackage/_get?'), httpOptions);
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" class="row-border hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>NAME</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody *ngIf="packagesArray?.length != 0">
          <tr *ngFor="let package of packagesArray">
              <td>{{ package }}</td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tbody *ngIf="packagesArray?.length == 0">
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" class="no-data-available">No data!</td>
        </tr>
      <tbody>
</table>
```

**JSON GET Response**

```
{
    "requestHdrs": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    "packageMap": [
        {
            "build": "161",
            "name": "WmTN",
            "description": "Trading Networks",
            "version": "10.1.0.0.161"
        },
        {
            "build": "",
            "name": "test",
            "description": "",
            "version": ""
        },
        {
            "name": "be_nrb_rst_shared_party_v2",
            "version": "2.0.0"
        }
    ],
    "packageNames": [
        "WmTN",
        "test",
        "be_nrb_rst_shared_party_v2"
    ]
}
```

Anyone got an idea?

Comment: If your doubt is with forkjoin , you can remove and just use that.packageToolkitService.getPackages().subscribe( directly. I don't see a need for forkjoin here, however that might not be a problem.

Comment: for further development I will need forkJoin, I made this example more easy than the code I have.

Comment: Just to confirm if the issue is with forkjoin , you can try with same above example and check without forkjoin? so that if that is the case , can look further on it.

Comment: I've tried, it gives the same problem.. all the results come on 1 page and the results disappear after searching